# Eloquent JavaScript: Can't understand recursion example

Tags: javascript

From page 50 of Haverbeke's second edition. I added a couple of console.log to try to better track the progress.

```
function power(base, exponent) {
  if (exponent == 0) {
    console.log("line 5 " + base + "  " + exponent); 
    return 1;
  }
  else
    console.log("line 10 " + base + "  " + exponent);
    return base * power(base, exponent -1);
}
console.log(power(2,3));
```

// Output

```
line 10 2  3

line 10 2  2

line 10 2  1

line 5 2  0

8
```

//

I expect the final output to be `1` since when the `if (exponent == 0)` is true, the next statement is `return 1;`, but it appears to enter the `else` one more time to return 8. But shouldn't the `return` kick us out of the function.

Obviously a newbie or wouldn't be stuck on page 50 of a supposedly beginner book.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please tell me that indentation is not actually from the book, it's horribly misleading. In fact, please tell me Haverbeke consistently uses braces, like a reasonable person. *Edit*: It's a [good news/bad news](http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html#h_jxl1p970Fy) situation: No, that indentation is not from the book. But no, he doesn't consistently use braces. *sigh*

Comment: I'm missing where the formatting is different. I added the braces because I was having a problem with more than one line below the if. I haven't gotten fully used to JavaScript formatting. Why are braces needed below the if and not the else. At least on my Mac that's how it works. Without the braces below the if, I get an error.

Comment: Cont. Haverbeck wraps from above the if to below the return in one set of braces. I see one response below where there are two sets of braces. One below the if and one below the else. Are the interpreters sloppy or is JavaScript. In any case with the pointer to the previous answer and the answers here I've got the solution. Thank you all.

Comment: JavaScript / JavaScript engines aren't sloppy. Braces following (most) control-flow constructs are optional if you have just one statement. In your code above, you have the line `return base * power(base, exponent -1);` indented as though it were part of the `else` block. It isn't and should be un-indented (even with the `else`). To make it part of the `else` block, you'd use `{` and `}`.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever the function enters the "else" branch, a new stack frame is created, waiting for the result of the recursive call. You can imagine the evaluation step by step:

1. `power(2, 3)` enters the `else` branch, and it returns `base * power(base, exponent - 1)`.
2. `2 * power (2, 2)` enters the `else` branch, and it returns `base * power(base, exponent - 1)`.
3. `2 * (2 * power (2, 1))` enters the `else` branch, and it returns `base * power(base, exponent - 1)`.
4. `2 * (2 * (2 * power (2, 0)))` enters the `if` branch, and it returns `1`.
5. You can finally evaluate the result: `2 * (2 * (2 * 1))`, which is `8`.

Answer (score 2):

The end result of the function call `power(2,3)` is not the last return, but the combination of returned values, by the subsequent internal function calls. Let's deconstruct the recursive function:

- `power(2,3)` returns `2 * power(2,2)`
- `power(2,2)` returns `2 * power(2,1)`
- `power(2,1)` returns `2 * power(2,0)`
- `power(2,0)` returns `1`

So in total, `power(2,3)` returns `2 * 2 * 2 * 1` which is equal to `8`.

Answer (score 1):

The `return` statement exits from **one invocation** of the function. In order to get to the `return 1;` line, the function will have been called several times (based on the original value of the exponent).

The first invocation is

```
console.log(power(2,3));
```

Inside the function, subsequent invocations take place here:

```
    return base * power(base, exponent -1);
```

Each one will correspond with a `return`.

Oh, and as @TJCrowder notes in a comment, that code is not correct: the `else` part should be wrapped in `{ }`:

```
if (exponent == 0) {
  console.log("line 5 " + base + "  " + exponent); 
  return 1;
}
else {
  console.log("line 10 " + base + "  " + exponent);
  return base * power(base, exponent -1);
}
```

I'm assuming that the missing `{ }` wrapper was a transcription error.

Comment: @Tordeck ha ha thanks I was just fixing that :)

Comment: And if braces are used consistently, the OP's editing error (having added the `console.log`s) would have been less likely. (Although in this case it was harmless, since the `if` returned and the `else` was effectively unnecessary.)